# Insert results of previous query in MongoDB returns syntax error

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the following JS script that queries the MongoDB collection and then stores query results to another:

```
var result1 = db.ctg.find( { b: { $lte: 878.4397930385701 } } );

db.statistika1_ctg.insert(
    result1.toArray();
);
```

When I try to load this script to mongo shell, I get the following error:

`2020-01-30T22:15:59.795+0100 E  QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list :`

`@(shell):2:17`

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of nested semicolon - that's a syntax error:

```
db.statistika1_ctg.insert(
   result1.toArray()
);
```